# most frequent observation or median of a set

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am aggregating data and I cannot sum certain columns so I would like to take the most frequent observation from that column, or the median value.  Example follows, thanks in advance.

ID    site

1    3

1    3

1   2

1   3

2   4

2  5

2  5

2  5

I want it to look like

ID   Site

1  3

2  5

Comment: Can you explain what your rule is for selecting the median vs. the most frequent value(mode)?  Or by median do you mean mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH temp AS(
  SELECT ID, Site, COUNT(*) As counts
  FROM id_table 
  GROUP BY ID, Site
)
SELECT temp.ID, temp.Site
FROM temp
JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(counts) max_counts
      FROM temp 
      GROUP BY ID
     )b
ON temp.ID = b.ID
AND temp.counts = b.max_counts
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/880e9/7)

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  How would I add this to an existing table?